# How to change programmatically the size of a Font defined in the Resource Editor?

Tags: java-me, lwuit, lwuit-resource-editor

In the `Resource Editor` I created a `Font` having a size of 9, and it is proportional, plain and small. Then I created also some `UIID` which are based on this `Font`. Now I want to change programmatically the `size` of this `Font` under certain circumstance , that is when the height or width of the `Display` is bigger than a reference value. The new value of the `Font` size will be then based on the `Display` size , so it's dynamic. So how to change programmatically the `Font` size of a `Font` defined in the `Resource Editor` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was a hard thing. You can't change programmatically the size of a Resource Editor's `Font`. You will need to build a `Font` by code and apply to the app by the `Style` class. For example if you want to change the `Font`of a `Label`, you must to create the `Font`, add it to a `Style` and add this to the `Label` using the `Component` method `setSelectedStyle()` or `setPressedStyle()`, there are so many methods....

Answer (score 0):

A resource theme is a Hashtable. Create another font for larger devices e.g. `"LargeFont"` then just extract it from the theme and apply it to the hashtable e.g.:

```
Font f = res.get("LargeFont");
Enumeration e = myTheme.keys();
while(e.hasMoreElements() {
    String current = (String)e.nextElement();

    if(current.indexOf("font") > -1) {
         // add this to a list of keys to change, I'm not sure if you can change them during  iteration
    }
}

// for every key to change
myTheme.put(key, f);
```

Now you have a theme with large fonts.